# Enable calculation history on OS X Calculator app?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to display the calculation history, like what is done in real calculators with a register tape?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can't believe that I didn't see this:

`Window | Show Paper Tape (⌘T)`

Comment: +1 I was searching in "Display" menu.

Comment: how is this accepted answer? This "history" is temporary and gets deleted when you exit the app

Comment: @Srneczek I was only interested in the "history" for the calculation being performed, so this feature was adequatet.